# new operator means in JQuery

Tags: jquery, plugins, new-operator

I came across this code in Internet. It is about a plugin that implements printing functionality. I am just wondering what does the *new* operator means while invoking the function.

```
$.fn.printArea = function( options )
{
  printWindow = new Popup();
  writeDoc = printWindow.doc;
}

function Popup()
{
    var windowAttr = "location=yes,statusbar=no,directories=no,menubar=no,titlebar=no,toolbar=no,dependent=no";
    windowAttr += ",width=" + settings.popWd + ",height=" + settings.popHt;
    windowAttr += ",resizable=yes,screenX=" + settings.popX + ",screenY=" + settings.popY + ",personalbar=no,scrollbars=no";

    var newWin = window.open( "", "_blank",  windowAttr );

    newWin.doc = newWin.document;

    return newWin;
}
```

If someone could explain the rational behind calling the popup function in new, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Something wrong here .. popup is just a function .. not a class. You can not use new 'operator' here

Answer (score 4):

The `new` operator creates a new `object` of `Popup()`.
This way, if you would have multiple different popups, you could create them by saying:

```
popup1 = new Popup();
popup2 = new Popup();
```

And then you would be able to give them their own parameters.

**EDIT thanks to pst in the comments**

This is not the situation here, however. Note that the "constructor" returns -- thus the "new object" is silently discarded and the object contained in newWin is returned.

Comment: Funny thing is, I wasn't even aware it worked this way in Javascript.

Comment: Funny thing is, So many people who know little about JavaScript work with it every day and the _internet_ still works!

Comment: I spend my time with OOP in PHP, haven't needed it for my Javascript yet (I think). Learn something new every day ;)

Comment: **This is not the situation here, however.** Note that the "constructor" `return`s -- thus the "new object" is silently discarded and the object contained in `newWin` is returned.

Comment: Yes, it seems like Raynos' answer in this case is more accurate.

Comment: @pst, Thanks a lot!  I didn't know the return at end will make it throw the new Popup object away.  Learned something new today.  :D

Answer (score 4):

```
printWindow = new Popup();
// is the same as
// create a new `this` scope for the Popup function from the prototype.
var temp_this = Object.create(Popup.prototype);
// call the function with the `this` context and store the result.
var o = Popup.call(temp_this);
// if the result is an object then assign it to the variable
// otherwise assign the `this` value to the variable.
printWindow = typeof o === "object" ? o : temp_this;
// It actually does more. Go read the ES5 spec.
```

In this case `Popup` is a silly constructor that returns an object anyway so the `new` keyword is useless because `this` is not returned internally.

It's simply valid but useless code for this Popup function.

Comment: The Popup() function itself returns a new *window* object, not a new instance of Popup().  However, I agree that the code itself is useless.

Comment: @shinkou I made some adjustments to the exampler code but it lots it's simplicity now :(

Comment: Thanks for clearing things up!  I haven't tried things like this before, and couldn't have even imagined.  :)

Comment: @shinkou defiantly use `new` or `Object.create` rather then this. But at least this is a "reasonable" illustration of what `new` does under the hood. Also be wary that `return "foo"` or `return 42` will not work and return the new object instead.

Answer (score 0):

A new instance of Popup (class) is instantiated and assigned to the variable printWindow.

Comment: It is a function and I can simply call it by the function name.

Comment: If you call it with the new keyword, the function can be viewed as a class, with windowAttr and newWin as its private properties.  It's confusing, but that's the way it works.  Take a look at this: http://mckoss.com/jscript/object.htm

Comment: @shinkou not really. it's different from that.

Comment: @Raynos, how different is it?

Comment: "**There is no class**. There is **no class?** Then you'll see, that it is **not the class** that bends, it is **only a function**." Also, note the `return` in the `Popup` *function*. `(new Popup()) instanceof Popup` is *false* in this case (it evaluates to a tricky Window object!).

Comment: @pst Spoon reference is the best.